# weighted sum of exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_i$ are i.i.d random variables and $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ i.e.
$Pr(X\le x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x \ge 0$. 
What is the density function of $Z=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_iX_i$ where $\alpha_i$ are constants?

Comment: Can you do it for $N=2$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This density can not be described using densities of standard r.v. You can read here about the full formula: http://www.ccms.or.kr/data/pdfpaper/jcms21_4/21_4_501.pdf, but if you ask for the homework, most likely you should use some local CLT.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion. I didn't notice that the scaling of an exponential r.v. is still exponential but with different mean. Then the question is changed to a summation of different exponential random variables which is solved in the suggested paper.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the weighted exponential random variable is still an exponential random variable. Only the mean is scaled with the same weight. Therefore, the sum $Z$ is an Hypo-exponential random variable and it is summarized in wiki's webpage [Hypoexponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution).

Comment: The hypoexponential is a sum of a serial of exponential distributions each with their own rate $\lambda_{i}$. It requires all the $\lambda_{i}$ ($a_i$ in OP's problem) distinct.